# How to distribute a 'drug' asset over a Supply chain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am designing a Supply Chain application in Hyperledger Composer. I have a drug asset which looks like this:

```
asset Drug identified by DrugId {
  o String DrugId
  o String DrugName
  o Integer qty
  --> Trader presentOwner
}
```

I have a Manufacturer to Wholesaler transaction:

```
transaction M2W {
  --> Drug drug
  o Integer qtyreq
  --> Wholesaler newOwner
}
```

How do I ensure that when I make a transaction, the asset with the Manufacturer is retained with a diminished quantity and a new asset is also created for the Wholesaler with the required quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Make two chaincodes named manufacturer and wholesaler and ensure both are on the same channel.

Manufacturer chaincode consists of a method named below:

```
item(ctx, DrugName, current quantity, quantity_to_be_supplied_to_wholesaler){
current quantity= current quantity-quantity_to_be_supplied_to_wholesaler;
drug={
DrugName
current quantity,
quantity_to_be_supplied_to_wholesaler,
}
```

save these details onto your ledger using

```
ctx.stub.putstate(drugID, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(drug)));
```

You must implement query_drug to query list of drugs stored on chaincode.

On the wholesaler chaincode you can retrieve the details of drug record using

```
 const response = await ctx.stub.invokeChaincode('Manufacturer', ['queryDrugs', drugId ], 'channel_name');
```

Then you can retrieve the drug record using,

```
 var r1=response.payload; //getting payload from response

 var s1=r1.toString(); // converting payload buffer to string.
 var s=JSON.parse(s1); //convert string to JSON object.
 var qty=s['quantity_to_be_supplied_to_wholesaler'];
```

You can then add qty to your wholesaler record by,

```
current quantity=current quantity+qty;
```

You can then add this qty to ledger using

ctx.stub.putState(ID, qty);

looks a bit messy, but hope it helps.